# SparkR, worker cannot load library

Tags: r, apache-spark, stringr, sparkr

I recently start using SparkR. I have 1 master and 3 worker running and AWS. I am using RSudio Server. My codes involve stringr package, and this packages have been installed to `/usr/share/R/library` on all nodes.

But when I run `SparkR:::map(data, function(x){str_replace(x, "XXXX", "XXxxx")})`, i get the error

```
could not find function "str_replace"
```

How can I load packages on worker nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access function from an library you have either load and attach it:

```
library(stringr) # Or require(stringr)
str_replace(x, "XXXX", "XXxxx")
```

or use double colon operator:

```
stringr::str_replace(x, "XXXX", "XXxxx")
```

Unfortunately `::` is quite expensive so if you prefer to keep your namespace clean you should consider creating a local binding:

```
str_replace <- stringr::str_replace
str_replace(x, "XXXX", "XXxxx")
```

On a side not using internal API with `:::` is probably not the best idea. Ignoring good practices it is simply far to slow to be useful in practice.